# Regarding usage of enums in C: would it be possible to change the value of enum members?

Tags: c, enums

So this might seem like a silly quesiton, but I was wondering if there was any way to change the values of members of an enum in C.

For instance, say I have:

```
enum yourcolor{red = 43, blue = 54, green = 89};

enum yourcolor blue-green = red*blue*green;
```

would there be a way to change the values of red, blue and green later on in the code?

I was thinking something like:

```
yourcolor.red = 56; etc...
```

I know you should use a struct for something like this, but this is just something I was thinking about today, and I can't find an answer to.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Enums are generally used when all of the enumerations are known beforehand -- would recommend a struct as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no" -- you cannot change the value of an enumeration constant after it has been defined.

Semantically, it would not make any sense to do so.  The whole point behind using enumerated types is to abstract away the underlying representation -- you care that a color is `red`, not 43 or 56 or whatever.  Put another way, if it *matters* that `red` is 43 or 56, then you shouldn't be using an enumeration.

When you create an object of an enumerated type, you're basically saying that the object can only take on one of those enumerated values; it can either be `red` or `blue` or `green`.  If you want to represent secondary colors, you would want to define enumeration constants for those secondaries.  You can define those secondaries in terms of expressions containing the primaries.  The following is one of many possible encodings:

```
enum color {black   = 0x00,              // binary 0000
            red     = 0x01,              // binary 0001
            blue    = 0x02,              // binary 0010
            green   = 0x04,              // binary 0100
            magenta = red | blue,        // binary 0011
            cyan    = blue | green,      // binary 0110 
            yellow  = red | green,       // binary 0101
            white   = red | blue | green // binary 0111
};
```

The encodings shown are convenient; they show how secondary colors are built from the primaries.  They're also *completely* arbitrary; you could define the type as

```
enum color {black, red, blue, green, magenta, cyan, yellow, white};
```

and not worry *at all* about the underlying values (which will be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7, respectively).

By creating this type, you're implying that an object of type `enum color` should *only* take on one of the values `black`, `red`, `blue`, `green`, `magenta`, `cyan`, `yellow`, or `white` (irrespective of the underlying integer value).

Of course, C"s not exactly strict about this: an object of enumerated type can hold an arbitrary integer value, even if that value doesn't appear in the list of enumeration constants.  But by doing so, you're breaking the conceptual model implied by the type.

Answer (score 2):

No. The identifiers in an `enum` are declared as constants.

From [C99](http://busybox.net/~landley/c99-draft.html#6.7.2.2) (emphasis mine):

> The identifiers in an enumerator list are **declared as constants** that
>   have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted

Note, later in the same section (italics mine):

> Each enumerated type shall be compatible with an integer type. The
>   choice of type is *implementation-defined*, but shall be capable of
>   representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.

More generally, I'd question the motivation for such a feature. An *enumeration*, by definition, is the *complete* listing of all members of some set, the values of which probably shouldn't be changing in normal circumstances.

Comment: As per the C99 spec, the type is implementation-defined by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. Well, it would work in different translation units, although that probably isn't what you want.

You can use a variable though:

```
typedef int color;
color red = 43;
color blue = 54;
color green = 89;
```

These can be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely, I think.  Enum values are likely replaced statically by constants at compile time, and so the behaviour of assigning to them is going to be wacky (at worst), or rejected as an error (at best).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like this would make sense. Enums are in fact constants and I assume they get hardcoded into machine instructions.

This means the program has no way of knowing when they change. If you changed it in a program that isn't linear, what would happen when you jumped back? Like in a loop or goto statement?